# ¿ Qué es un snapshot y dónde sucede uno en este código?

Tags: java

Tengo entendido que un bucle *for each* recorre ordenadamente los elementos de un conjunto para ahorrarte la definición de sentencias dentro del bucle *for* estándar.

He leído un código en el que **aseguran que aquí hay presente un *snapshot*, pero yo solo veo un *for each***.

Mi primera pregunta: ¿ qué es un snapshot ?

A continuación, el código:

```
public void removeAll(PositionList<E> list, E e){
    for(Position<E> p : list.positions()){
        if(p.element().equals(e)) list.remove(p);
    }
}
```

donde el método *removeAll* debe eliminar todas las apariciones del parámetro *e* en la lista *list* (también dada como parámetro). El método *positions* devuelve un cursor de tipo *Position* para poder iterar sobre la lista.

Así pues, ¿ dónde está el snapshot ?

Comment: "He leído un código en el que aseguran que aquí hay presente un snapshot, pero yo solo veo un for each." En qué parte aseguran o nombran la palabra snapshot? Puedes compartir ese texto para saber el contexto? Un snapshot es la copia de el estado de un sistema o tambien una variable

Comment: Lamento decirle que no hay contexto. Es un ejercicio que te da un enunciado que dice: implementa el método removeAll, que debe eliminar las ocurrencias de "e" en "list". Eso es todo. Luego, dicen que la solución que ellos dan usa un snapshot. Así de gratuito.

Comment: Creo que a lo que se refiere con snapshot es que `Position<E> p` es un snapshot de cada elemento de `list.positions()`. Es decir, al ser un snapshot, por mas que modifiques `p` no estaras modificando el elemento de la lista, si no un snapshot o una copia

Comment: Pues daré entonces eso por hecho. Gracias